# Получить cookie

Tags: javascript, vue.js, symfony, axios

Пишу свое первое rest api приложение. Никак не могу разобраться, как получить куки на стороне клиента(vue.js)
Отправляю запрос на сервер

```
  axios
            .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login?email=test@test.ru&password=123123123')
            .then(response => {this.info = response;})
```

На бэкенде(Symfony 4) возвращаю jwt

```
setcookie ("jwt", $jwt, $expireTime, '/',  "", $useHttps, true );
```

1) Как мне теперь поймать эту куку на стороне клиента?
2) Где и как его хранить?
3) И как передавать на сервер?

Comment: 1. В ответ на запрос возвращаете jwt токен
2. На фронте этот токен записываете в cookies (если сам записал в cookies, то и как получить его понятно)
3. При каждом запросе передаете токен в Auth header

Answer (score 1):

1) Как правило, в аутентификации через jwt токен, его отправляют как ответ на запрос, а не ставят в куки;
2) Фронт ловит ответ, извлекает токен и записывает его в localStorage;
3) Токен передаётся на сервер через заголовок Authorization: Bearer your-token

Comment: 3) Т.е. каждый раз, когда я буду отправлять запрос на сервер, мне нужно будет отправлять токен?

Comment: да, нужно отправлять с каждым запросом

Comment: api изначально использовалась для работы с desktop или mobile приложениями, а у них нет никаких механизмов для хранения данных между запросами, как cookie у браузеров. Поэтому был придуман такой подход, а только потом начал применяться на фронте

Comment: Получилось реализовать эту схему. Но возникла пара вопросов: 1) Как мне продлевать время истечения этой "сессии" авторизации? Каждый раз на сервере когда получаю jwt проверять срок и если что его увеличивать, а потом возвращать клиенту? 2) С точки зрения безопасности это нормально, что клиент может взять и декодировать jwt? Или нужно еще как-то шифровать данные?

Comment: 1) Да
2) Что вы имеете ввиду под декодировать jwt?

Comment: 2) Например, пользователь авторизовался и в ответ получил такой jwt `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo2LCJlbWFpbCI6InR1c3QxMTFAdHVzdDExMS5ydSIsImV4cCI6MTU5MDczMzU5N30.ImD06n6EmqXQnga98Ccd4LmL0nlgiUrr1yfCOL22Bjg`. Пользователь может декодировать через какой-нибудь сервис (например: https://jwt.io/) и посмотреть данные. С точки зрения безопасности это нормально, если перехватят запрос или пользователь  изменит время истечения авторизации?

Comment: Прошу прощения, если задаю глупые вопросы, но делаю первый раз и хотел узнать все нюансы

Comment: У jwt токенов в генерации участвует соль, так что если пользователь её не знает, то декодировать он её не может. Тем более, если не ошибаюсь, jwt токен хранит только id пользователя и срок, а это не такая уж и секретная информация